# Проблема с конектом до mysql с помощю миграций laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker

database.php :

```
 'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'mysql'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'notes'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'notes'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'asf9#89hf9384h'),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

my.conf:

```
[mysql]

[mysqld]
default_authentication_plugin= mysql_native_password
```

.env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=notes
DB_USERNAME=notes
DB_PASSWORD=asf9#89hf9384h
```

Ошибки при php artisan migrate:

```
>  Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = notes and table_name = migrations)

  at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668| 

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("PDO::__construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]")
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:68

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=mysql;port=3306;dbname=notes", "notes", "asf9#89hf9384h", [])
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:68

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Comment: [Может это поможет](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1392#issuecomment-368308494)

Answer (score 0):

database.php :

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE={{Database}}
DB_USERNAME={{username}}
DB_PASSWORD={{password}}
```